# How to get only categories with images in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I have a huge list of subcategories in a category.
When opening that category, I need to display only the subcategories that have images set.
Is there a way to filter the category collection to display only categories that:

- Are children of a specified category ID
- Have images set

Comment: You're currently fetching all products from a category -- you're question asks about how to get categories. What do you want products or categories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Magento collections & queries:

You can use a Magento category_collection to build a query. Magento collection queries extend Zend queries so you can use a lot of things a Zend query would allow you to use (or you can get the zend query and alter it directly).

One nice addition that Magento collection queries bring is the fact that you can filter by EAV attributes (it adds all the necessary table joins to fetch the attributes).

Another nice addition of Magento collections is the fact that it fetches information from either the current store if available or from the default store.

### Answer:

```
$categories = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
    ->addFieldToFilter('image', array('notnull' => true))
    ->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', $categoryId)
    ->setStoreId(2);
```

In our case both `image` and `parent_id` are simply fields in the `catalog_category_entity` table, they are not EAV attributes so we can use `addFieldToFilter`. If they were EAV attributes we should use `addAttributeToFilter`.

### Flat tables:

There is also an issue regarding how these queries work when flat tables are enabled I don't remember what the catch was exactly. For example I just tested this query using `addAttributeToFilter('image'` even though the `image` is a Field not an attribute, and the query worked for me because the shop I tested it in is using flat tables (in flat tables attributes are converted to fields).

### Impact on server:

There are a few performance elements to monitor:

1. communication between PHP and SQL (number of individual queries)
2. complexity / efficiency / speed of individual queries
3. PHP data processing
4. PHP memory usage
5. HTML/CSS/JS/Images files download time
6. HTML/CSS/JS/Images rendering time

And there are a few performance enhancements built into Magento:

1. Flat tables and other indexes (reduces the overhead of EAV SQL queries) reducing the complexity of many SQL queries (reduces the impact of issue nr.2)
2. Caching -- either file cache, memcached or other -- reduces the number of individual SQL queries as well as a lot of PHP data processing (reduces the impact of issues nr.1 and 3.)
3. Merging and minifying CSS and JavaScript files (reduces the impact of issues nr.5 and 6)
4. Resizing the images from a normal full size to a thumbnail size -- this should reduce having to download big images and having to render them into small areas (also reduces the impact of issues nr.5 and 6)

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for! Thank you!
Will this reduce the impact on the server if there are lots of subcategories ?

Comment: "Impact on the server" is a loose term.

Comment: There are many products inside many subcategories in that category. Right now it takes about a minute to load. If only 10 of them have images and I use this way to select them.. do you think it will take less time to load the main category ? That was my question :)

Comment: The query I offered you does not load any of the products. So it does not change anything with regards to how many resources loading products uses.

Comment: What do you mean it takes 1minute to load? Does it take 1 minute to receive the full response from the server (server-time) or 1 minute to load the response from the server, render the HTML/CSS and load all related images (browser-time)?

Comment: For a typical Magento install showing tens of products per page: The usual server-time is less than 5 seconds. The usual browser-time is less than 10 seconds.

Comment: If you're showing 100+ products per page with images then the browser-time might get bigger.

Answer (score 0):

To display the category image in place of a category name.

```
<?php
    //gets all sub categories of parent category 'Brands'
    $cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(6)->getChildren();
    $catIds = explode(',',$cats);

    $categories = array();
    foreach($catIds as $catId) {
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId); 
        $categories[$category->getName()] = array(
            'url' => $category->getUrl(),
            'img' => $category->getImageUrl()
        );
    }

    ksort($categories, SORT_STRING);
?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($categories as $name => $data): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $data['url']; ?>" title="<?php echo $name; ?>">
                    <img class="cat-image" src="<?php echo $data['img']; ?>" />
                </a>
            </li>   
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

Comment: I know how to get the images. I need to filter the ones that do not have an image to reduce the load on the server.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy you're running an SQL query retrieving the current category and another SQL query for each subcategory. That's just wasteful.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy use a category collection and filter all categories to either being of current categoryId or having a parent with that categoryId and you've only used one single SQL query.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy you can further filter that query to check if the category has an image or not before even loading it as a Magento object sparing not only SQL querries but also PHP processing and memory.

Answer (score -1):

Look this [Click - Magento page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/5026/)

Comment: As a matter of "good practice" on StackOverflow answers should be self-contained. Meaning outside links and resources should be used as either "reference" or "further reading" not as the main content of the answer. This is because this answer should be relevant to any future visitor and if your outside link gets broken the answer becomes useless.